# Chat room color theme is too bright

Tags: bug, design, chat

The current version is way too bright.

It would be superb if we had color theme we can customize for the chat room.

If such feature is too much to ask, I at least desire to tone down the color a bit.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the *"input-area"* CSS, there is a missing image:

```
background: #000 url("//cdn.sstatic.net/gamedev/img/bg-notify.png") repeat scroll 0% 0%;
```

Which makes the background of the input area ridiculously bright.